# Sed: Extracting regex pattern from lines

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I have an input stream of many lines which look like this:

```
path/to/file:             example: 'extract_me.proto'
path/to/other-file:             example: 'me_too.proto'
path/to/something/else:             example: 'and_me_2.proto'
...
```

I'd like to just extract the `*.proto` filenames from these lines, and I have tried:

```
[INPUT] | sed 's/^.*\([a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.proto\).*$/\1/'
```

I know that part of my problem is that `.*` is greedy and I'm going to get things like `e.proto` and `o.proto` and `2.proto`, but I can't even get that far... it just outputs with the same lines as the input. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's answers! Did not expect so much help all at once... I wish I could accept them all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it helpful to use extended regex for this purpose (`-r`) in which case you need not escape your brackets.

```
sed -r 's/^.*[^a-zA-Z0-9_]([a-zA-Z0-9_]+\.proto).*$/\1/'
```

The addition of `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` forces the `.*` to not be greedy.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tag your command with [linux](/questions/tagged/linux), I'll assume you have GNU grep. Pick one of

```
grep -oP '\w+\.proto' file
grep -o "[^']+\\.proto" file
```

Answer (score 1):

one way to do it:

```
sed 's/^.*[^a-zA-Z0-9_]\([a-zA-Z0-9_]\+\.proto\).*$/\1/'
```

- escaped the `+` char
- put a negation before the alphanum+underscore to delimit the leading chars

another way: use single quote delimitation, after all it's here for that:

```
sed "s/^.*'\([a-zA-Z0-9_]\+\.proto\)'.*\$/\1/"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this `sed`:

```
sed "s/^.*'\([a-zA-Z0-9_]\+\.proto\).*$/\1/"
```

`+` - Extended-RegEx. So, you need to escape to get special meaning. `The preceding item will be matched one or more times.`

Another way:

```
sed "s/^.*'\([^']\+\.proto\)'.*$/\1/"
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E "s/.*'([^']+)'$/\1/"
```